# ASP.Net MVC multiple list return from Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, return

I am working with the mvc4 razor, this is the first model  code

```
public class WebLicenses
{
    public string WebLicenseName { get; set; }
    public int CustomerWebLicensesCount { get; set; }
}

public class WebApplication
{
    public string WebApplicationName { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    public string Never { get; set; }
}
public class griddetail
{
    public griddetail( List<WebLicenses> wl1,List<WebApplication> wa1 )
    { 
        wl =wl1;
        wa = wa1;
    }
    //public List<WebLicenses> wl2 { get; private set; }

    public List<WebLicenses> wl { get; set; }
    public List<WebApplication> wa { get; set; }

}
```

this is my second model code which uses the first model code as (here stored procedure return 2 table - WebLicenses, WebApplication  (In below code error comes --commented)

```
public IEnumerable GetOutlookGridDetail(string customerId = "")
{
        List<WebLicenses> weblicenses = new List<WebLicenses>();
        List<WebApplication> webapplication = new List<WebApplication>();            
        griddetail returnValue = new griddetail(weblicenses, webapplication);          

        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SLIMConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("selectCustomerDetail", cn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter param_CustomerID = new SqlParameter("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10);
        param_CustomerID.Value = customerId;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param_CustomerID);

        try
        {
            cn.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                WebLicenses newRecord = new WebLicenses();
                newRecord.WebLicenseName = Convert.ToString(reader["WebLicenseName"]);
                newRecord.CustomerWebLicensesCount = Convert.ToInt32(reader["CustomerWebLicensesCount"]);
                //returnValue.Add(newRecord);
                weblicenses.Add(newRecord);                    
            }

            reader.NextResult();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                WebApplication newRecord = new WebApplication();

                newRecord.WebApplicationName = Convert.ToString(reader["WebApplicationName"]);
                newRecord.Count = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Count"]);
                newRecord.Never = Convert.ToString(reader["Never"]);
                webapplication.Add(newRecord);
            }
            returnValue.wl.Add(weblicenses); //here comes error (Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SLIM.Models.WebLicenses>' to 'SLIM.Models.WebLicenses')
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // returnValue = null;
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();

            if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                cn.Close();
            }
        }

        return returnValue;
}
```

this is my controller code.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GridViewPartialView(string recordId)
    {
        IEnumerable result1 = (new SlimHomePageData()).GetRecords(recordId, "");
        IEnumerable result2 = (new SlimHomePageData()).GetRecords();
        List<object> finalResult = new List<object>();
        finalResult.Add(result1);
        finalResult.Add(result2);
        return PartialView("OutlookGridDetail", finalResult);            
    }
```

I want to return a single list which consists 2 lists (but above error comes). Also suggest, Is this right approach as stored procedure return multiple tables and we want to set value in view via a model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I forgot to give answer, but yesterday somebody gives minus vote. Yes its too long time. What I did (I again explain everything to understand more) :

**Step1:** Define the 2 class as

```
public class WebLicenses
    {
        public int WebLicenseID { get; set; }
        public string WebLicenseName { get; set; }
        public int CustomerWebLicensesCount { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    }

public class WebApplication
{
    public int appID { get; set; }
    public string WebApplicationName { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    public bool Never { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}

public class griddetail
{
    public griddetail(List<WebLicenses> wl1, List<WebApplication> wa1)
    {
        weblicences = wl1;
        webapplication = wa1;
    }

    public List<WebLicenses> weblicences { get; set; }
    public List<WebApplication> webapplication { get; set; }        
}
```

**Step2:** change in controller as

1. Change return type `IEnumerable` to `griddetail` class
2. At the end declare and assign this nested class in a `griddetail` class

   ```
   public class SlimHomePageData
   {
        private SLIMDataContext dc = new SLIMDataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SLIMConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
   .
   .
   .

    public IEnumerable GetOutlookGridDetail(string customerId = "")
   {
       List<WebLicenses> weblicenses = new List<WebLicenses>();
       List<WebApplication> webapplication = new  List<WebApplication>();            
      //remove from here and add at the end of this method 
      //griddetail returnValue = new griddetail(weblicenses, webapplication);          

      SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SLIMConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("selectCustomerDetail", cn);
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      SqlParameter param_CustomerID = new SqlParameter("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10);
      param_CustomerID.Value = customerId;
      cmd.Parameters.Add(param_CustomerID);

      try
      {
       cn.Open();

       SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

          if (reader.HasRows)
           {
               while (reader.Read())
               {
                   WebLicenses newRecord = new WebLicenses();
                   newRecord.WebLicenseName = Convert.ToString(reader["WebLicenseName"]);
                   newRecord.CustomerWebLicensesCount = Convert.ToInt32(reader["CustomerWebLicensesCount"]);
                   weblicenses.Add(newRecord);
               }
           }

           reader.NextResult();
           if (reader.HasRows)
           {
               while (reader.Read())
               {
                   WebApplication newRecord = new WebApplication();

                   newRecord.WebApplicationName = Convert.ToString(reader["WebApplicationName"]);
                   newRecord.Count = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Count"]);

                   bool never = false;

                   if (reader["Never"] != DBNull.Value)
                   {
                       bool.TryParse(reader["Never"].ToString(), out never);
                   }

                   if (reader["EndDate"] != DBNull.Value)
                   {
                       newRecord.EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["EndDate"]);
                   }

                   newRecord.Never = never;

                   webapplication.Add(newRecord);
               }
           }


       reader.Close();

      }
      catch (Exception)
      {
          // returnValue = null;
      }
      finally
      {
          cmd.Dispose();

          if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
          {
              cn.Close();
          }
      }

          griddetail returnValue = new griddetail(weblicenses, webapplication, webcustomapplication, maintenance, smartcv, histry, doc);
       return returnValue;
      }
     .
      .
     }//closing of my SlimHomePageData class
   ```

**Step 3:**In ActionMethod changed as :After posted this question I changed in the method, but you can use the same method concept in above question. Later I need another class to add `result1` while return.

```
      public ActionResult GridViewPartialView()
{
          return View();
}


[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult childGridViewPartialView(string recordId, string filtervalue, string flag)
        {
            if (flag == "GridRowChanged")
            {
                IEnumerable result1;
                griddetail result3;
                if (recordId != null)
                {
                    result1 = (new SlimHomePageData()).GetRecords(recordId, "");  //another result to be add later at the end of action method
                    result3 = (new SlimHomePageData()).GetOutlookGridDetail(recordId); //this was in my question
                }
                else
                {
                    result1 = new List<SlimHomePageRecord>();   //another result to be add later at the end of action method
                    result3 = (new SlimHomePageData()).GetOutlookGridDetail(recordId); //this was in my question
                }

                List<object> finalResult = new List<object>();
                finalResult.Add(result1);
                finalResult.Add(result3);
                return PartialView("OutlookGridDetail", finalResult);  
            }
            else
            {
                return PartialView("childGridViewPartialView", (new SlimHomePageData()).GetRecords(null, null));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

the instance weblicenses is a List type. It looks like it should be a single instance of WebLicenses.

You may want to add the newRecord instance to the returnValue.wl list instead of the list instance.

Edit:
You don't need to add anything to the wl list properties because you are adding to the WebLicenses list. The property wl on returnValue is a reference to the WebLicences instance so if you add to WebLicences then wl will show the same addition.